# How to import Oracle database with preserving index-constraint relation

Tags: oracle, import, indexing, constraints

In Oracle 11g when one creates a unique constraint:

```
alter table abc add constraint uk_name unique (name);
```

then also a unique index is created on that column. When one drops this constraint:

```
alter table abc drop constraint uk_name;
```

then also the corresponding index is dropped. However, when the index is created separately before the constraint and later the constraint is created - the constraint will work ok and use the pre-existing index, but.. when the constraint is dropped as described above the index is NOT dropped.

Now, when doing a database import indexes are created before the constraints and so after dropping a constraint the corresponding index will not be dropped - this leads to a different state of database and if someone writes some migration scripts then they will leave undeleted index and this might lead to errors. There is a possible workaround, instead of:

```
alter table abc drop constraint uk_name;
```

write:

```
alter table abc drop constraint uk_name keep index;
drop index uk_name;
```

but I'd like to know if it's possible, and how, to perform a database import with preserving this constraint-index relation? So if on database A it holds that after dropping the constraint the index will be automatically dropped than after import to database B the same should hold. Oracle database is so mature technology that it should be possible, and nasty workarounds are not required, yes?

**EDIT :**

I found out that instead of

```
alter table abc drop constraint uk_name keep index;
drop index uk_name;
```

one can just write:

```
alter table abc drop constraint uk_name drop index;
```

which is a much less ugly workaround..

Answer (score 0):

I would not recoment to mess with dictionary, but here is *posible* flag that could be used to know if index was created automatically or not:

http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/drop-constraint/

Another workaround would be

1. drop constraint
2. if index that was used by constriant is still present in dictionary - drop it